# Commutativity on $PGL(V)$ can be rised to $GL(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, abelian-groups

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and let $A_1,A_2\in PGL(V)$ such that $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$ in $PGL(V)$.

Can I take representants $M_i\in GL(V)$ of $A_i$ for $i=1,2$ such that $M_1M_2=M_2M_1$?

Written in another way the question: if two matrices satisfy
$$
M_1M_2=\lambda M_2M_1,\text{ for some }\lambda\in K^*
$$
then $\lambda=1$. How can I get this? Applying determinant, I obtain that $\lambda^{d}=1$, if $d=\dim(V)$.